# Unity error converting quaternion to euler rotation

Tags: javascript, unity

When I try to run my game in unity, it comes up with the error:

```
No appropriate version of 'UnityEngine.Quaternion.Euler' for the argument list '(UnityEngine.Quaternion)' was found.
```

When using the update code in (written in javascript):

```
transform.Rotate(Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation * Quaternion.Inverse(GameObject.Find("Main Camera").transform.rotation)));
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Quaternion.Euler` creates a Quaternion from three euler angles either by parameter list of floats or a Vector3 of the angles, not from a Quaternion [(see docs)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html):

```
public static Quaternion Euler(float x, float y, float z);
```

OR

```
public static Quaternion Euler(Vector3 euler);
```

Did you mean to write:

```
transform.Rotate((transform.rotation * Quaternion.Inverse(GameObject.Find("Main Camera").transform.rotation)).eulerAngles);
```

eulerAngles